# Handle validation failure in exception filter, and re-render view

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation, fluentvalidation

I'm using ASP.NET Core and FluentValidation.

When a POST action receives invalid input, it's customary to re-render the input form view, with validation errors:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return View("nameOfViewRenderedByGetAction", model);
```

But my validation is actually performed in a service, by FluentValidation, which throws `ValidationException`. I want to handle it in an exception filter:

```
public class ValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // only handle ValidationException
        var ex = context.Exception as ValidationException;
        if (ex == null) return;

        // re-render get action's view, or redirect to get action
        // ??
    }

}
```

I'm stuck at the "??" part, because Core has changed the signatures of many types, and `ExceptionContext` doesn't surface the data I need to make this work.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

It's a little late for an answer but I have a working solution for exactly the same application design. I use ASP.NET Core 3.0 and FluentValidation 8.x.

```
public class MvcValidationExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private IModelMetadataProvider ModelMetadataProvider { get; }

    public MvcValidationExceptionFilterAttribute(IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider)
    {
        ModelMetadataProvider = modelMetadataProvider;
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Design", "CA1062:Validate arguments of public methods", Justification = "Framework calls without null")]
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is ValidationException ex)
        {
            var validationResult = new ValidationResult(ex.Errors);
            validationResult.AddToModelState(context.ModelState, null);
            context.Result = new ViewResult { ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(ModelMetadataProvider, context.ModelState) };
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

As this filter has a dependency we can't use the Attribute directly but register it with dependency injection in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<MvcValidationExceptionFilterAttribute>();
```

To use the ExceptionFilter either apply it via the ServiceFilterAttribute:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(MvcValidationExceptionFilterAttribute))]
public class MyController : Controller
{
```

Or apply it globally in Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add<MvcValidationExceptionFilterAttribute>();
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

From an exception filter, You can render a custom view by setting the context result.

```
public class ValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // only handle ValidationException
        var ex = context.Exception as ValidationException;
        if (ex == null) return;

        // re-render get action's view, or redirect to get action
        var result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "GetView" }
        context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        context.Result = result;
    }

}
```

Where `GetView` should be the name of your Get action's view.

Sample exception filter that uses a custom developer error view to display details about exceptions.

```
public class CustomExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    private readonly IModelMetadataProvider _modelMetadataProvider;

    public CustomExceptionFilterAttribute(
        IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment,
        IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        _modelMetadataProvider = modelMetadataProvider;
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (!_hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // do nothing
            return;
        }
        var result = new ViewResult {ViewName = "CustomError"};
        result.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(_modelMetadataProvider,context.ModelState);
        result.ViewData.Add("Exception", context.Exception);
        // TODO: Pass additional detailed data via ViewData
        context.Result = result;
    }
}
```

Note that the above code is sending the context, model state and exception to the view.

In case all you need is custom error page refer to [ASP.NET Core Error Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling)

Generally, you should not be using an exception filter to turn an error into success. Consider using an action filter if you have a requirement like that.
Having said that, for some reason if you still need to redirect from an exception filter, this is how it can be done

```
   public class CustomExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public CustomExceptionFilterAttribute(
            IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment,
            IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }

        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            if (!_hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // do nothing
                return;
            }

            var result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Error" }));
            context.Result = result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It renders that specific view, not redirect. And it renders without validation errors, so that info is lost.

Comment: You cannot use an exception filter to turn an exception into a success. However you can pass the data you need. I have edited the answer.